# MySql CASE statement not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql statement that is not working as it should. I have tried and looked for solutions as I thought I might have been doing something wrong but I can't figure it on my own so I decided to take some help from the great minds around the globe on it. Here is my MySql statement.

```
select
    truncate(sum((cvdm.TimeOut - cvdm.TimeIn)/60),2) as HoursWorked,
    emp.EmployeeNo,
    cvdm.VisitDate,
    concat(emp.FName, ' ',emp.LName) as EmployeeName, 
    case truncate(sum((cvdm.TimeOut - cvdm.TimeIn)/60),2) when truncate(sum((cvdm.TimeOut - cvdm.TimeIn)/60),2) > 130 then 1 else 0 end as FTStatus
from employees emp 
inner join visit_details cvdm on cvdm.EmployeeNo = 
emp.employeeno
where cvdm.VisitDate between StartDate_ and EndDate_
and emp.ClientID=AgencyId_
group by emp.employeeno;
```

Now I have a problem with the case statement. The query returns 134 for HoursWorked (first column), but when I subject the same HoursWorked to CASE (refer to the last column returned from the query) it always returns 0, where in this particular case it should have returned 1. What am I doing wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: user as `CASE WHEN truncate(sum((cvdm.TimeOut - cvdm.TimeIn)/60),2) > 130 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FTStatus`

Comment: thanks man.. you are life saver :)